# Angular firebase upload images

Tags: firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner working with Angular 5 and firebase. 
As practice I decided to create a blog.
My problem is that I can not upload my images in firestore. When I upload to Cloud storage and try to retrieve the download link, it does not register in firestore.

Take a look at my code and give me suggestions.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/shared/services/auth.service';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { PostsService } from 'src/app/shared/services/posts.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;

  title: string;
  content: string;
  description: string;
  image: string = null;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
    private toast: ToastrService,
    private postService: PostsService,
    private store: AngularFireStorage,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createPost() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let data = {
      content: this.content,
      image: this.image,
      description: this.description,
      publication: new Date(),
      title: this.title
    };
    this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
    this.postService.create(data);
    this.title = '';
    this.description = '';
    this.content = '';
    this.toast.success('Votre article a été publié');
  }

  uploadImage(event) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let path = `posts/${file.name}`;
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
      return alert('Erreur, ce fichier n\'est pas une image');
    } else {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
      let ref = this.store.ref(path);
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
      let task = this.store.upload(path, file);
      this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
      console.log('Image chargée avec succès');
      task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL();
          this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
            console.log(url);
          });
        }
        )
      ).subscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-8">

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile03" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon03" (change)="uploadImage($event)" accept=".png,.jpg" [(ngModel)]="image">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile03">Choisir une image</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress" [hidden]="!uploadPercent">
          <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="{{ uploadPercent | async }}"></mat-progress-bar>
          {{ uploadPercent | async }}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!image">
          <img [src]="image || '//:0'">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title"> Titre du post </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Titre" required [(ngModel)]="title"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description"> Description </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Desciption"
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ajouter une breve description de l'article" required [(ngModel)]="description"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="content"> Contenu de l'artcle </label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" cols="15" rows="5" placeholder="..." required [(ngModel)]="content"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" (click)="createPost()">Poster l'article <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"
            aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

      </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrXVU.png)

Comment: Nicely written first question - you could help us by including the console output so we can see which of your messages go off (and the failure exception)

Comment: Thank you for your interest. By the way there is no mistake just that in Cloud storage, the upload is done perfectly but when recovering the download link to save it in firestore, in the console firebase it displays something like
**C: \ fakepath \ 72e39b1d336__CI_W28_S4_Jumia-Trust-2.jpg**
instead of the download link so that it can be displayed by the user.